# Delete a folder using Wix

Tags: wix

I recently tried to create an installer for my application using Wix. When I uninstalled the application all my folders and files were deleted except some created at run time by the application. After some research I found out that the reason was because those folders and files were created after the install proccess. I also found out that what I wanted to use would be the element RemoveFolderEx. Unfortunatly, I am having some trouble to use the tag. This is my current code that doesn't work:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="App" Level="1">
  ...
  <ComponentRef Id="deeletappdata" />
</Feature>

<Component Id="deeletappdata" Guid="*" Directory="AppDataFolder">
  <util:RemoveFolderEx Id="RemoveAppDataAppContent" On="uninstall" Property="AppDataAppFolderDir" />
</Component>

<Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
  <Directory Id="AppDataAppFolderDir" Name="$(var.Application)"/>
</Directory>
```

How can I use the element RemoveFolderEx?

Comment: Please describe why it's not working, such as error messages you get, or if the folder still exists, etc.  Any log messages related to this would be helpful too.  Also, you may want to have it log the value of $(var.Application) to make sure it's set to what you expect at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a folder inside %AppData% with wix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384560/how-to-delete-a-folder-inside-appdata-with-wix)

Comment: Please don't double-post your questions. It looks like you've already posted this one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384560/how-to-delete-a-folder-inside-appdata-with-wix